# JavaScriptの配列の呼び出しについて

Tags: javascript

変数arrayのi番目を呼び出すことはできますか?
できるとしたら、これで良いのでしょうか?

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4];
var i = 0;
console.log(array[i])
```

(変数iの中に配列の何番目かが入っています)

Comment: まずはご自身で実際に試してみて、結果がどうなるか確認してみましょう。意図した通りに動かない場合などに改めて質問した方がよいかなと。

Comment: 分かりました、試してみます。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 実行をためらう気持ちはすごくわかりますが、コンピュータに聞いたほうが僕たちよりも詳しいし、間違いがないですよ

Comment: 実際に実行してみたら出来ました。次回からは試してから質問する事にします。